# in js.cytoscape limit the mouse scroll function

Tags: javascript, cytoscape

I am using in  js.cytoscape library and the diagram is generated statically for a demo.
Now I am facing an issue with the mouse scroll, which Zooms in and out so much.

Is there a way to control this? I have seen the same happens in the provided demos. But it is not acceptable. Any work around.

Appreciate the help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property **wheelSensitivity** changes that fast scroll behaviour, when you give it a value between **0** and **1**, so just put this in your code:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: yourContainer,
  elements: yourElements,
  style: yourStyle,
  layout: yourLayout,
  wheelSensitivity: 0.5
});
```

If you have more questions like this, consider looking at the [documentation](http://js.cytoscape.org) of cytoscape, where you can find the answer most of the time. If you can't find the solution, feel free to ask on stackoverflow :)

Another thing, please show us what you already tried via code. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have added in to the layout.

  layout: {
    name: 'dagre',
    rankDir: 'LR',
    animate: false,
    panningEnabled:true,
    wheelSensitivity: 0.01

  },